# Run code after AceEditor instance is initialized

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

How can I run a javascript function after an AceEditor instance is initialized? If I had two inputs that I turn into AceEditor on one page, the function would run twice, once for each editor.

If possible I would like to set it once (some sort of default behavior).

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what exactly do you mean by "initialised".

After calling `editor = ace.edit(domNode)` ace instance is ready to use, if you want to know when the first time editor renders something to dom, you can use

```js
editor.renderer.once("afterRender", console.log)
```

Or force it to render synchronously with

```js
editor.resize(true)
```

If you are not including the default mode in the page and want to know when the mode is loaded you can use

```js
editor.session.once("changeMode", console.log)
```

If you are looking for something else update the question with more information.